# Site taking 5 minutes to load homepage - mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

The server is running apache2, and when trying to load a webpage it can take up to 5 minutes to load the homepage.  All internal pages seems fine however.  Checking the Error Logs I see the following:

```
[warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but can you install another webserver? Nginx and lighttpd are good products, open source, 1000x times faster and easier to setup.

Comment: Not right now I'm afraid - there's two clients who have websites that are currently down - I need to get them up and functioning again ASAP.  But thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

if you use mod_fcgid try change MaxRequestsPerProcess for more request